# How to merge two ordered singly linked list into one ordered list

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to merge two ordered singly linked list. I tried searching where the problem is but I am not able to find the answer. The output is not what I am expecting. **Output is given below**

```
class Test
{
Node head;  // head of list
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d){
        data = d; 
        next = null; 
    }
}

void sortedInsert(Node newNode)
{
     Node current;
     if (head == null || head.data >= newNode.data)
     {
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
     }
     else {
        current = head;
        while (current.next != null && current.next.data < newNode.data)
            current = current.next;

        newNode.next = current.next;
        current.next = newNode;
     }
 }
 Node newNode(int data)
{
   Node x = new Node(data);
   return x;
}

 /* Function to print linked list */
 void printList()
 {
     Node temp = head;
     while (temp != null)
     {
        System.out.print(temp.data+"-> ");
        temp = temp.next;
     }
     System.out.print("null\n");
 }

 Node mergeLists(Node list1, Node list2) {
    Node result;
    if (list1 == null) return list2;
    if (list2 == null) return list1;
    if (list1.data < list2.data) {
        result = list1;
        result.next = mergeLists(list1.next, list2);
    } else {
        result = list2;
        result.next = mergeLists(list2.next, list1);
    }
    return result;
}

 /* Drier function to test above methods */
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     Test oneList = new Test();
     Test twoList = new Test();
     Test joinList = new Test();
     Node l1,l2,join;

     //First linked list
     l1 = oneList.newNode(11);
     oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
     l1 = oneList.newNode(13);
     oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
     l1 = oneList.newNode(12);
     oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
     l1 = oneList.newNode(17);
     oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
     l1 = oneList.newNode(15);
     oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
     l1 = oneList.newNode(19);
     oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
     System.out.println("First List");
     oneList.printList();

     //Second Linked List
     l2 = twoList.newNode(1);
     twoList.sortedInsert(l2);
     l2 = twoList.newNode(5);
     twoList.sortedInsert(l2);
     l2 = twoList.newNode(3);
     twoList.sortedInsert(l2);
     l2 = twoList.newNode(7);
     twoList.sortedInsert(l2);
     l2 = twoList.newNode(4);
     twoList.sortedInsert(l2);
     l2 = twoList.newNode(19);
     twoList.sortedInsert(l2);
     System.out.println("Created Second Linked List");
     twoList.printList();

     join=joinList.mergeLists(l1,l2);
     System.out.println("Merge");
     joinList.sortedInsert(join);
     joinList.printList();
 }
 }
```

OUTPUT:

First List

> 11-> 12-> 13-> 15-> 17-> 19-> null

Created Second Linked List

> 1-> 3-> 4-> 5-> 7-> 19-> null

Merge

> 19-> null

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Shouldn't the merge be joinList.head = mergLists(oneList.head, twoList.head);   ?

Comment: Are you trying to merge two sorted linked list into one?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is in the main method

```
 oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
 l1 = oneList.newNode(15);
 oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
 l1 = oneList.newNode(19);
```

`l1` is the list 19 -> NULL and the same for `l2` 19 -> NULL. So the merge seem correct, the problem is that you are overwriting `l1` and `l2` with the last element rather than the first. I hope this helps.

Comment: No even if I change 
oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
l1 = oneList.newNode(15);
oneList.sortedInsert(l1);
l1 = oneList.newNode(21);

Then the answer is 21->null now. I want both the list to be merged and sorted. But I am not able to do that.

Comment: Can you try removing the assignment l1 = in all l1 = oneList.newNode(x); except the first one.

Comment: No that is not going to work. Is there any other way you can tell ?

Comment: have a method getHead() in Test that returns the head or else have a different variable for the first newNode() i.e., head1 = new Node(5); l1 = new Node(6)...

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to do this recursively, because if the lists are even moderately large you will overflow the stack. Merging two lists is a simple iterative operation. The basic idea is:

```
if (list1 == null) return list2;
if (list2 == null) return list1;

Node head = null;
Node l1 = list1;
Node l2 = list2;

if (l1.data < l2.data)
{
    head = l1;
    l1 = l1.next;
}
else
{
    head = l2;
    l2 = l2.next;
}

Node current = head;
// while not at end of either list
while (l1 != null && l2 != null)
{
    if (l1.data < l2.data)
    {
        current.next = l1;
        l1 = l1.next;
    }
    else
    {
        current.next = l2;
        l2 = l2.next;
    }
    current = current.next;
    current.next = null;
}
// at this point, you are at the end of one or both of the lists
// Pick up the potential remainder from the list that's not at the end.
// Note that only one of these loops will be entered.
while (l1 != null)
{
    current.next = l1;
    current = current.next;
    current.next = null;
    l1 = l1.next;
}
while (l2 != null)
{
    current.next = l2;
    current = current.next;
    current.next = null;
    l2 = l2.next;
}
return head;
```

That's the simple verbose solution. You can reduce the amount of code a bit by creating a method that appends a node to the new list, but the logic is the same.